# Manually passing form data to classic asp page fails

Tags: html, forms, asp-classic, parameter-passing

Passing form values to the asp page from a standard html form works, but trying to pass them manually does not. Is this some oddity with ASP classic? To outline the situation, I have the following standard form:

```
<form name="login" id="login" method="post" action="login_process.asp">
<input name="userName" type="text" size="30" maxlength="100" />
<input name="password" type="password" size="30" maxlength="100" />
<input name="Submit" type="submit" class="btn" value="Login" />
</form>
```

On the receiving end (login_process.asp), I have this:

```
if Request.Form("Username") <> "" and Request.Form("Password") <> "" then
' do stuff here
```

Now the odd thing is that this form has been in place for years and actually works. But if I try passing values manually to login_process.asp the values never make it:

```
www.zzz.com/login_process.asp?username=some_user&password=some_password
```

I added some checks to login_process.asp to see if I could pull the vars from the submit before they were processed like so:

```
myUsername = request.form("Username")
myPassword = request.form("Password")
response.write "user=" & myUsername
response.write "pass=" & myPassword
```

and all I'm getting is

```
user=pass=
```

So obviously the data isn't getting passed. But why? What am I overlooking? Passing form data is basic stuff so what gives?

Any insights appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are no longer using the form if you are passing them on the querystring, So **Request.Form** won't work. You need to use **Request.QueryString** instead.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Steve! And curse my lack of ASP knowledge!

Comment: NOTE  - The advantages of using GET based Requests is that it makes it easier to pass things back and forth dynamically between multiple pages.  One downside is now your form length is infinite, being its now the length of the  URL bar.   And the more characters you offer your user, the more elaborate the exploits can become.   Obviously, also do validation, NEVER trust your user to do what they are suppose to do, and also, never trust your variables to by the type of data you intended, always validate, and count the lengths, and use REGEX and REPLACE when possible.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

We can use "Request.Form" to get form field data into other page. For this please try below code :

```
<form name="login" id="login" method="post" action="login_process.asp">
<input name="userName" type="text" size="30" maxlength="100" />
<input name="password" type="password" size="30" maxlength="100" />
<input name="Submit" type="submit" class="btn" value="Login" />
</form>
```

And we get the form data in login.process.asp page is something like this :

```
<%  Response.Write(Request.Form("userName"))   %>
```

It will display userName value

Comment: +1 for this being the actual answer based on the question asked,  since he wants to pass from a form to the next page, and not, per-say, pass them from page to page to page.